# Text whitespaces correcter

Tags: whitespace, punctuation

The basic idea of what I need is whitespace correction (but more things could be appreciated too!): `I am in a park  ( with her , not him ) .` => `I am in a park (with her, not him).`

Whitespace correction could be regexp'ed, but I need to have all the **language specific rules** (it would be nice to have that sorted out in a library!). Actually I need to do that for French text, and punctuation spacing rules are different than in English for example.

I don't know if NLTK (python) can help me doing that for example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can ask the native speakers for more help but a good and complete French Grammar book might suffice.